# sql procedure using loop prints false result

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to write a simple procedure that takes as parameters a table name and a column and just prints the result.

this is my code :

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST(TAB IN VARCHAR2, COLUMN IN VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
    FOR REC IN (SELECT COLUMN FROM TAB) LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(REC.COLUMN);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

And then I executed it with:

```
EXECUTE TEST('CLIENTS2', 'NOMCLI');
```

Problem is this always returns:

```
NOMCLI
NOMCLI
NOMCLI
NOMCLI
NOMCLI
NOMCLI
NOMCLI
NOMCLI
NOMCLI
NOMCLI
NOMCLI
NOMCLI
NOMCLI
NOMCLI
NOMCLI
NOMCLI
NOMCLI
```

My table isn't empty and when I directly try to execute the query it works perfectly.
What seems to be the problem please? Thank You!

Comment: Which dbms???  The syntax is different for different dbms.

Comment: So `Oracle` is your dbms.  So add `Oracle` tag to your question.

Comment: IIRC, you still need to open a cursor for this, and probably also build dynamic sql (read: unsafe sql). So much better not to use a loop, and  SELECT the column into a result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure output is correct. Your code is explicitly querying the [`TAB`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/TAB.html) view (obsolete but still available for backward compatibility), and the parameter named `COLUMN` is a string constant with the value `'NOMCLI'`, so the query will return that value for every row in `TAB`.

PL/SQL compiles using the code as supplied at compile time, and does not apply any implicit runtime substitutions just because evaluating some variable could give the name of a database object. I am pretty sure such an approach would be unworkable. If you want dynamic code, you have to code it explicitly.

[Read more about dynamic code in PL/SQL.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html)